# Powershell I would like to display message in Console when running a powershell script

Tags: powershell

The script is as follows.
`Write-Host "Installation text and guidelines"`

where do I place the Write-Host code so that it displays in the console when the below code is executed in powershell?

```
`Using Module '.\Monitoring.psm1'

[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [ValidateSet('Single', 'Multiple')]
  [string] $Architecture = '',
  [string] $AzureTenantId = '',
  [switch] $SkipUserCheck
)

try {
  Import-Module -Name "$($PSScriptRoot)\lib_pwsh\Instrumentation.psm1" -Force
  Import-Module (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "\Monitoring.psm1") -Force

  Send-Event "Evaluating dependencies"

  $depCheck = Test-Dependencies

  if ($null -ne $depCheck){
    foreach ($_ in $depCheck){
        Send-Event $_ -WriteOutput
    }
    throw "Dependency evaluation failed. Terminating uninstallation. "
  }

  Connect-Azure -SkipUserCheck:$SkipUserCheck

  $controlParameters = [MonitoringUninstall]::new()
  $controlParameters.ManualSelection = $false

  Do {
    Get-UninstallArchitecture -controlParameters $controlParameters
    Clear-Scrollback
  } Until ($controlParameters.IsValid())

  Uninstall -controlParameters $controlParameters
}
Catch {
  Send-Event -Message ("{0}`n{1}" -f $_.Exception.Message, $_.ScriptStackTrace) -WriteOutput

  Send-Error -Message "An error has occured:`n $_" -Exception $_.Exception

  If ([Environment]::UserInteractive) {
    Read-Host "Press enter to continue and exit"
  }

  Exit
}
`
```

I tried to place the code above the 'Using Module' but it was giving an error. I need it to display the installation and guidelines message in the console window while the script is running.

Answer (score 0):

What is your error saying?

```
Write-Host "Installation text and guidelines"
```

I'm guessing the error is not 'Write-Host' related. In this case Write-Host should be executed but an error would be generated because of '`using'.

Try Import-Module..

Comment: Yes, thats right. But where can I place the write host so that there is no error?

Comment: What is your error saying? Write-Host should not give an error.

'Using' is no PowerShell syntax but PHP etc.